# How to describe "all modes"

Tags: meaning-in-context, idiomatic-language

I wrote:

> The average distance travelled per person **by all modes of transport**
> increased, with cars being the primary means of transport in both
> years.

My freelancer deleted "by all modes of transport". His version is:

> The average distance travelled per person increased during this
> period, with cars being the primary mode of transport in both years.

Is "by all modes of transport" an idiomatic way to describe the category in the red box? If I omit it like the freelancer did, will people know that the first clause is about all modes?

[image]

Comment: Could you get a different freelancer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I agree with the deletion in this case. As written, "The average distance travelled per person by all modes of transport increased" could be parsed as each individual mode increasing, which the table shows isn't the case (for example, walking distance decreased). Without the "all modes of transport" it's clearer that we are referring to just the total average distance travelled by each person increasing. By default, "the average distance travelled per person per year" would include all modes of transport, without needing that to be specified.